create 3d omx file in python
I want to create a 3d omx file of shape (4,4,4) where 4 are each origin and destination and also 4 are timeperiods (AM, MD, PM, OP) using 8 matrices given below. I am looking at two variables Travel time, and Distance. I can refer to the github page to create/append multiple matrices in one omx file. However, it is not clear how to create a single 3d omx file from multiple matrices (numpy arrays) with explicitly mentioning the time periods.
The example data is given below:
Travel time AM











1.79
0.06
1.26
1.00


0.06
0.36
0.88
0.65


1.26
0.88
1.42
1.75


1.00
0.65
1.75
1.71



Travel time MD











1.43
0.05
1.01
0.80


0.05
0.29
0.70
0.52


1.01
0.70
1.14
1.40


0.80
0.52
1.40
1.37



Travel time PM











1.86
0.06
1.31
1.04


0.06
0.38
0.92
0.68


1.31
0.91
1.48
1.82


1.04
0.68
1.82
1.78



Travel time OP











1.30
0.04
0.92
0.73


0.04
0.26
0.64
0.47


0.92
0.64
1.04
1.27


0.73
0.48
1.28
1.24



Distance AM











2.98
0.1
2.1
1.67


0.1
0.6
1.47
1.08


2.1
1.46
2.37
2.92


1.67
1.09
2.92
2.85



Distance MD











2.98
0.1
2.1
1.67


0.1
0.6
1.47
1.08


2.1
1.46
2.37
2.92


1.67
1.09
2.92
2.85



Distance PM











2.98
0.1
2.1
1.67


0.1
0.6
1.47
1.08


2.1
1.46
2.37
2.92


1.67
1.09
2.92
2.85



Distance OP











2.98
0.1
2.1
1.67


0.1
0.6
1.47
1.08


2.1
1.46
2.37
2.92


1.67
1.09
2.92
2.85



I have tried using attribute to differentiate between different time periods, but its not helpful. For example,
myfile = omx.omx.open_file('myfile1.omx','a'): myfile['Distance'].attrs.timeperiod = 'AM' myfile['Distance'].attrs.timeperiod = 'MD' myfile.close()
